# addActionListener argument is incorrect

Tags: java

In the program I want to use actionListener to monitor a TextFrame. I created a class called monitor and there is a constructor which invoke the whole TextFieldFrame, TFFrame.

```
class Monitor implements ActionListener{

TFFrame tf = null;

public void Monitor(TFFrame tf){
    this.tf = tf;
}
```

In the TFFrame class, I add a actionListener which invoke itself.

```
class TFFrame extends Frame{
TextField num1, num2, num3;
public void launchFrame(){
    num1 = new TextField(10);
    num2 = new TextField(10);
    num3 = new TextField(20);
    
    Label plus = new Label("+");
    Button equal = new Button("=");
    
    equal.addActionListener(new Monitor(this));
```

However the compiler fails with an error and the error is that the argument in the Monitor is incorrect. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ActionListener is an interface and has only one required method:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

You don't appear to have actually implemented that method here. Normally it's called under the hood when an appropriate event occurs.

I think you may not be using events and listeners correctly. Logically speaking, given what I understand from your example code, you'd have something like this:

```
TFFrame tf = new TFFrame();

tf.addActionListener( new Monitor() );
```

One problem is that the frame has it's own set of events and will not communicate the events from clicking buttons or focusing on textfields up through the frame to the listener. The frame's events are what will end up calling the actionPerformed method that you should have in Monitor.

You could certainly add other stuff to your custom listener, but the listener generally doesn't contain a reference to thing its listening to. Perhaps what you really wanted was just an actionlistener to check when the equals button is pressed, in which case you'd have something like this.

```
TFFrame tf = new TFFrame();

tf.launchFrame();
```

Inside of the launchFrame method you would add an action listener to the equals button with some kind of listener for buttons.

```
equals.addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
```

Now for that to work you'd have to create a class called button listener that implements action listener, and then write the appropriate event handling code inside of it's actionPerformed method.

P.S.
To be perfectly honest, much of this inference. If I'm wrong about what you want, then I'd recommend you go and read through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html